# Display 30 video frames in a second in php

Tags: php

I've written a C++ program for an embedded system. My program processes images taken by a camera (**350 fps or even more** ) and apply some machine vision algorithms on them. I wrote the result of my program which is an jpg image in a specific location in my hard-drive (e.g localhost/output/result.jpg)

Now I want to write a PHP code for displaying this image every 30 ms or faster (it depends to the output of my c++ program .... sometimes it is 30 fps and sometimes 10 or 40 but never more than 40 !!!) the video frames are not related to each other so I cannot use a streaming video since these algorithms suppose the frames are sequential ....

It is possible that the PHP code reads a corrupted image (Since, one program wants to write and the other one wants to read)

I thought to use a mutex concept here ... create a flag (text file) which is accessible to both programs whenever my C++ program wants to write into the same location set the flag high (write something in the text file) and when it finished the writing clear the flag so when php code sees that flag waits until the image is written into the hard drive and then displays it ....

I'm familiar to C++ but completely new to php, I'm able to display images in php but I don't know how to use timers in a way that the above problem would be solved.

what should I do ? I put a code which works but I don't want to use it since it makes only this part of the webpage be updated (Because of while(1)) ? is there any alternative solution ? if I'm not able to display more than 20 frames per second, what frame rate is possible in this scripting language ? what factor plays the role in this thing ?

Thanks

My Code:

```
<?php
while(1)

{
        $handle = @fopen("/var/www/CTX_ITX/Flag_File.txt", "r");
        if ($handle) {
                 if(($buffer = fgets($handle, 10)) !== false) 
                         {
                            if($buffer=="Yes)
                                {
                                    echo "<img src = "result.jpg" alt='test' \>";
                                }
                         }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
sleep(.01); //10 ms pause before starting again ....
}
?>
```

Comment: Aside from the missing `"` in your script; if you want 30 fps, you stream video; you don't display a series of images in an HTML page using any scripting language

Comment: And reading the docs for [sleep()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) would tell you that it accepts an __integer__ value as a number of seconds, not a float.... if you want to sleep for fractions of a second, you use [usleep()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php)

Comment: Then I suggest you also learn how web scripting works in PHP (and most other scripting languages).... it executes code from beginning to end, then sends data to the browser and terminates execution.... it doesn't send a data page, wait, send another data page, wait again, etc

Comment: I know that :) ... I didn't know what to use !!!  in my case it works for 0 seconds .... I added some more information

Comment: please propose what should I do, Since I want to know if the output of my embedded systems works ...

Comment: Stitching these images into a video stream in real time is not something you're going to be able to do in PHP. You might be able to simulate it with [binaryjs](http://binaryjs.com/) but I doubt if you'll get 30fps

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not suitable for your task. It responds to a request. Your JS would have to load the image every 30ms.
I would suggest you take a look at Node.JS and HTML5 WebSockets. This technology will enable you to theoretically send pictures fast enough without reconnects etc. (only if your connection is fast enough to handle the traffic)

Comment: if I reduce the frame rate to 5 fps, Would I have the chance to show it or not ?!!! if yes, how to remove the while(1) statement so the rest of the code runs too ...

Comment: you will always have the chance to show the pictures. Frame rate on the browser depends on your connection speed. You might want to skip frames to keep the output better in sync with what's going on on your server

Comment: Forget that `while`..... you're not running PHP as a daemon process... PHP should simply display the current existing image and then terminate.... and the front end (browser) js should then request the next image as a new request